# Why is my response call out of scope and not working? NodeJs, Bcrypt, Express, MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express, scope

I am using Nodejs and MySQL to validate user passwords. I am having a hard time accessing my response (res) object to send a response back to the client. For some reason it works above my bcrypt function but not below. I need to access it below so I can send my JWT token back to the client. See below code examples. Thanks.

```
**WORKING EXAMPLE**
**res.send(data) is properly sending data back to the client**

app.post("/login", jsonParser,(req, res) => {
    let selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?';  
    let query = mysql.format(selectQuery,["users","username", req.body.username]);

    pool.query(query,(err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
//works here---> res.send(data)

        let match = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, 
        data[0].password)
        console.log(match)
        
        match ? token = generateToken(data[0]): token = null
    })
})
```

```
**NON-WORKING EXAMPLE** 
**res.send(data) is NOT sending data back to the client. TIMED OUT**

   app.post("/login", jsonParser,(req, res) => {
    let selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?';  
    let query = mysql.format(selectQuery,["users","username", req.body.username]);

    pool.query(query,(err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
     
        let match = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data[0].password)
        console.log(match)

//not here----> res.send(data)
    
        match ? token = generateToken(data[0]): token = null
    })
})
```

```
**The same code using try catch**
app.post("/login", jsonParser,(req, res) => {
    let selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?';  
    let query = mysql.format(selectQuery,["users","username", req.body.username]);

    pool.query(query,(err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        try {
            let match = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data[0].password)
            match ? token = generateToken(data[0]): token = null
          }
          catch (exception_var) {
           console.log('exception', exception_var)
          }
          finally {
            res.send(token)
          }
    })
})
```

```
function generateToken(data) {
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
    console.log('inside generate token!', data)
    const payload = {
      data: data.username,
      //department: data.department,
      subject: data.id,
    };
    console.log(payload,'payload')
    const options = {
      expiresIn: "1d",
    };
    return jwt.sign(payload, secret, options);
    
  }
```

Comment: hi! welcome to stackoverflow! 
a few questions: what does `compare()` return?
can you add a try-catch block around those 3 last lines? I think it's throwing an error and the response is never sent back

Comment: @germanio Hi, thank you! I've updated the code above to make it more readable. My compare sync function returns true with the correct password and false with the incorrect pw. I added the try catch but its not throwing any errors and it still wont send a response. It validates my pw just fine and generates the token but won't send a response of any kind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bcrypt.compare is a asynchronous function. So, your can use it in two ways. Use callback function or Use async await

```
app.post("/login", jsonParser,(req, res) => {
    let selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?';  
    let query = mysql.format(selectQuery,["users","username", req.body.username]);
    pool.query(query, async (err, data) => {   // Declare the function as async function
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        const match = await compare(req.body.password, data[0].password)   // wait for the data from function
        const token = match ? generateToken(data[0]) : null
        res.send(token)
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi Prana, thanks for your response. When I add await to the code like shown above I get err: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules.

Comment: Did you add pool.query(query, async (err, data) => {  this line. (Consider adding async keyword)

Comment: Hi Prana, I added async to the pool.query params and it got rid of my async await error but I am still unable to send a server response after the bcrypt function. I can see that the function is returning true and its generating my token but I can't send the response. My console.log(match) after the function works but not res.send(). Thanks.

Comment: In your response, you need to send only the result from the query. Is it or you need to send the response from the compare function?

Comment: I need to get the result ---> compare it using bcrypt ---> generate a token ---> send the token to the user in the response.

Comment: Ok then you have to send token. Not data?

Comment: I just found that res.status() is deprecated and they advise to use res.sendStatus() instead but I still have my issue. It looks like I can't send a response from inside any function's in my endpoint. Another possible solution is how do I get a variable out of the function's scope and into its parents scope.

Comment: Can you explain about your generateToken function. Is that async function?

Comment: I don't think so @Prana. I just included my generate token function above. It seems to work fine.

Comment: @DanielMilano I've updated the answer. Can you check it out?